# Deck of Cards combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

**{A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J ,Q ,K}  and four suits - {Hearts, Diamonds, Spades, Clubs} . A Hand is a set of 5 cards picked up from the standard deck. How many different hands contain at least one  of the following two cards :  {K of Hearts, Q of Diamonds} ?**

I'm having a little trouble finding the answer to this problem. I know that since two cards out of 5 have to be certain cards, that the choices for the other 3 cards is C(50,3). I also know that there are C(52,5) choices of possible hands for a deck of cards. However, I'm not sure what I would do if I needed to count the total number of hands containing the specified cards, but I'm thinking it would contain some sort of indirect counting method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

- You already know that there are $C(52,5)$ choices of possible hands for a deck of cards in total
- How many possible hands include neither the King of Hearts nor the Queen of Diamonds?